# Image metadata in blob storage to cosmos

Tags: metadata, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

What is the simplest way to transfer image metadata I have stored for each image in a container to cosmosDB on the Azure portal? For clarification I am trying to retrieve the image properties I have specified as key value pairs under metadata, not the default image metadata. I have attached an image of what I am referring to. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NG50.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think using logic app is relatively simple, the design of logic app is as follows:

[image]

You can first use `List blobs` to list all your images, then use `for each` to traverse the blobs and use `Create or update document` to save the image metadata in cosmosDB.

I have tested it for you and found no problems.